# Do the magnitudes of the Jacobian eigenvalues correlate with convergence?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-theory

Consider a dynamical map at a fixed point (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stability_theory)):

> There is an analogous criterion for a continuously differentiable map $f$: $R^n → R^n$ with a fixed point $a$, expressed in terms of its Jacobian matrix at $a$, $J_a(f)$. If all eigenvalues of $J$ are real or complex numbers with absolute value strictly less than 1 then a is a stable fixed point; if at least one of them has absolute value strictly greater than 1 then a is unstable.

If I have two maps $A, B$, each with their largest eigenvalue as $|\lambda_A| \ll |\lambda_B| < 1$, can I make any conclusions that map $A$ converges onto its fixed point faster than map $B$?

Comment: If this question was unclear or uninformed, please let me know with a comment rather than down-voting (or do both, I'm less worried about the points, and more want to understand the problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in a sense.  But if you compare the convergence rates of *individual* points, the relation can be reverse.

Consider linear maps, identified with their matrices,
\begin{equation}
A = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2 \end{bmatrix}, \quad B = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_3 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_3 \end{bmatrix},
\end{equation}
where $0 < \lambda_2 <\lambda_3 < \lambda_1 < 1$.  Clearly, the speed of convergence of $B^{k} x$ is $\lambda_3$, for any $x \in R^2$.  Now, the speed of convergence of $A^k x$ is $\lambda_1$, *but only* for $x = (x_1, x_2)^{\top}$ with $x_1 \ne 0$.  The speed of convergence of $A^k (0, x_2)^{\top}$ is $\lambda_2$ (which is $< \lambda_3$).

In the nonlinear case, assume that $J_a(f)$ has an eigenvalue $\overline\lambda$ of multiplicity $l$ with the largest modulus, and that the remaining eigenvalues have moduli less than some $\mu < \lvert \overline\lambda \rvert$.  Then there exists, in a nbhd of $a$, a "very stable" $(n - l)$-dimensional invariant $C^1$ submanifold, tangent at $a$ to the sum of the invariant subspaces corresponding to those eigenvalues with moduli less than $\mu$.  On that "very stable" manifold the convergence to $a$ is at least as strong as $\mu$, whereas the remaining points close to $a$ converge to $a$ not faster than with speed $\lvert \overline\lambda \rvert$. For a reference, see, e.g. Theorem 4.1 on p. 326 of: C. Chicone, *Ordinary Differential Equations with Applications*, Texts in Applied Mathematics 34, Springer, 2006.

Comment: I think the *simple* answer is that real part of eigs needs to be less than one for flows (linear differential equations) and modulus of eigs less than one for maps. 

This would be the better answer if cleaned up.

Comment: First, that would not be an answer to the OP's question.  Second, you apparently mean "... to be negative for flows ..."?

Comment: Yes, sorry ... negative for flows. Thanks.